# cURL cPanel not working with one domain

Tags: php, ssl, curl, cpanel

My server installed cPanel.

I want to get information from one link. I a using cURL

With this code

```
$postfields = array('code'=>'somecode', 'email'=>'email@gmail.com');
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://domain.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($postfields));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($result);
```

It's working on localhost and other server but not working on my server. I tried curl with ssh connect it's working with others domain (HTTP and HTTPS).

This is the error showing

> curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to

PHP INFO

> PHP Version: 5.6.25
>
> cURL support: enabled
>
> cURL Information: 7.38.

Please help me.

Comment: How do you specify `my server`? (Why can't you use `localhost`?)

Comment: Because i am running that code in shared hosting.